# How to send custom array of objects with post body?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

There is data classes `PlaylistInsertOperation`, `TrackId` and function `insertTracks` via Retrofit Interface.

```kotlin
data class PlaylistInsertOperation(
    val tracks: List<TrackId>,
)

data class TrackId(
    val id: String,
    val albumId: String
)

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/patch")
suspend fun insertTracks(
    @Field("diff") diff: List<PlaylistInsertOperation>
): PlaylistResponse
```

When I send request, field `diff` equals the next string

```
diff=PlaylistInsertOperation(tracks=[TrackId(id=39117009, albumId=5034819), TrackId(id=89341636, albumId=18635889)])
```

But need to such string

```
diff=[{"tracks":[{"id":"61081889","albumId":9499401}]}]
```

How to tell `gson` or `retrofit` parse models without data class name?

Comment: Make it json string then pass it... Formdata allow text or file only

Comment: @GobuCSG why it can json -> model with list, but cant model -> json string?

Comment: if you're using Gson converter try Gson().toJson(diff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create additional data class `PlaylistDiffRequest` with list of `InsertTracksOperation`. And override `toString` function that call `gson`.

```
// Retrofit Interface
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/handlers/playlist-patch.jsx")
suspend fun patchPlaylist(
    @Field("diff") diff: PlaylistDiffRequest,
): PlaylistResponse
```

```
// Models
data class InsertTracksOperation(
    val tracks: List<TrackId>,
)

data class PlaylistDiffRequest(val diff: List<Any>) {
    override fun toString(): String = Gson().toJson(diff)
}
```

In this case output field will be as I need

```
diff=[{"tracks":[{"albumId":"6250697","id":"35629702"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass JSON object in **@FormUrlEncoded**. You can use **@Body** annotation to pass JSON

```
@POST("/patch")
suspend fun insertTracks(
    @Body body: PlaylistInsertOperationRequest
): PlaylistResponse
```

Create another class for request

```
data class PlaylistInsertOperationRequest(
   @SerializedName("diff") val diff : List<PlaylistInsertOperation>
)
```

Comment: Based on API implementation only we can pass.  Formdata won't be read your request from body

Comment: can you post screen shot of your postman request ?

Comment: I don't have... I know node.js as per my knowledge body and formdata parse different in server side

Comment: If you could try this solution. I am more than 50% sure this gonna work!